# how to invoke a function from the result of another function

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func Reverse(str string) string {
    r := ""
    for i := len(str) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        r += string(str[i])
        // fmt.Println(r)
    }
    return r 
}

func Generate(str string) string {
    str = Reverse(str)
    // vowel := ""
    for _, rne := range str {
        if rne == 'a' {
            str += "A"

        }
        if rne == 'e' {
            str += "E"

        }
        if rne == 'i' {
            str += "I"

        }
        if rne == 'o' {
            str += "O"

        }
        if rne == 'u' {
            str += "U"

        }
    }

    return Reverse(str) 
}
```

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(...("haigolang123"))
}
```

This program will accept a logic from the previous function, then combine it with the next function.
I wondering how to invoke a function from the result of another function.
expect output is "321gnAlOgIAh"

Comment: Replace `...` with `Generate`. Note that your Generate calls Reverse twice which seems redundant.

Comment: do you mean by changing to like this fmt.Println(Generate("haigolang123")), but the output is AIOAhaigolang123, not to be "321gnAlOgIAh"

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. The reason the output is not what you want is because the algorithm of `Generate` is incorrect. See https://go.dev/play/p/qxdGpJ1U900

Comment: alright, i see. i'll practice more about writing the algorithm, and ask more i guess (; thanks a lot

Comment: You Call the Reverse() function two times inside Generate()

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get why you are trying to reverse the string twice if your input is `haigolang123` and expected output is `321gnAlOgIAh`. Let's refactor step by step.

1. For vowels, if all you needed to do is convert lower case to upper, you can direct subtract number 32 from rune (since 'a'=97 & 'A'=65). So, use a function to common out the check.

```golang
func in(c rune, list []rune) bool {
    for _, l := range list {
        if c == l {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

This can check as follows:

```golang
vowelsLower := []rune{'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}
# Some code here
if in(c, vowelsLower) {
    result += string(c-32)
}
```

2. There are many ways to append strings, [refer here](https://golangdocs.com/concatenate-strings-in-golang) when working particularly with strings. However, we are working with runes. It is easier to append it to a byte slice. Looking at the bigger picture, []byte can be directly converted to string when needed.

```golang
var result []byte
# Some code here
if in(c, vowelsLower) {
    result = append(result, byte(c-diff))
}
```

While returning,

```golang
return string(result)
```

This is [your code with these changes](https://go.dev/play/p/4lNC9hJSD68).

3. Additionally, why to iterate twice (once in `Generate`, and again in `Reverse`). Try reverse iterating and do the vowel case switching. The noticeable difference of this approach is it uses bytes directly.

> Range over string gives `rune`. Slicing the string gives `byte`. Of course they can be typecasted from one another.

Since we were already using bytes in previous approach, the code looks like [this](https://go.dev/play/p/OrZDsKUvOA6).

Happy coding!!